# undefined method 'api_key' for nil:nilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working on an application and having some trouble logging into the application. When I submit username and password to the app, I get:

`undefined method 'api_key' for nil:NilClass`

in the :

`app/controllers/user_sessions_controller.rb:51:in 'create'`

The create method is below:

```
def create
 user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])

 if (user && user.authenticate(params[:password]))
    render json: {logged_in: true, access_token: @user.api_key.access_token}
  else 
 render json: {logged_in: false, access_token: nil}
 end
end
```

I'm pretty sure this syntax works since it correctly generates the access token in the user controller, but for some reason it is throwing the error here.

Answer (score 2):

`user` is not the same as `@user`.

`@user` is an instance variable, `user` is local to the method.

Which to use depends on what you need, but you likely want to use one *or* the other.

```
def create
  @user = User.find_by_username(params[:username])
  if (@user && @user.authenticate(params[:password]))
    render json: {logged_in: true, access_token: @user.api_key.access_token}

 ...
```

Comment: ah thank you, very helpful. sorry for asking such a basic question, just starting out with rails